# Selecting files and zipping it in android

Tags: android, zip

I am developing an Android app which needs to select files from the storage system and zip it up, then have a command run on it.

I've tried picking the files using the following code:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*,video/*");              
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);                
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
```

Can someone help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

File selecting code looks fine. But here is a example of it. See this [link](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/08/android-how-to-select-file.html).
Android have huge native support for zipping and unzipping a file. Here is some examples which might help you.

zipping a file

```
public void zip(String[] _files, String zipFileName) {
    try {
        BufferedInputStream origin = null;
        FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(zipFileName);
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                dest));
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

        for (int i = 0; i < _files.length; i++) {
            Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files[i]);
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files[i]);
            origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);

            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files[i].substring(_files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
            out.putNextEntry(entry);
            int count;

            while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            origin.close();
        }

        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

See [this](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-programmatically-zip-and-unzip-file-in-android) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) for further description.

Comment: how to include the files that i have picked from storage!? which variable represents the files that i selected?                                                                 Uri uri = data.getData();
String filePath = uri.getPath();  where to put this filepath?

Comment: Have you go through the developers doc?

Comment: remove the loop from the method i posted above. Change it's parameters and pass file path to it. But check in docs which parameters zipEntry() method take.

Comment: As far as I know zip entry takes one parameter. One file only. So try to pass the file path to it.

Comment: no bro! and where should i include this zip function,inside onActivityResult?

Comment: Kindly read the both docs. And try to work on it. rather then trying to get a code to copy paste and run.